# Помогите разобраться с выводом информации из БД

Tags: php, sql

Возникает ошибка -

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in W:\domains\benefit.com\libs\database.php on line 23

Хотя подключение в норме и  `mysqli_query` возвращает *true*.

```
class db{
private static $mysqli_link = null;

public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db_name)
{
    self::$mysqli_link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name)
        or die("Ошибка подключения". mysqli_error(self::$mysqli_link));          
}

public static function query($query) //Функция выполняет действия mysqli::query - @return mysql_result
{
   return $result = mysqli_query(self::$mysqli_link, $query)
       or die("Ошибка запроса".mysqli_error(self::$mysqli_link));
}

public static function read_first_line($query, $type = MYSQLI_ASSOC) //Функция выполняет чтение превой строки результата запроса - @return array
{
    $ret = self::query($query);
    return $res = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, $type);
}
}

$db = new db($mysqli_config['host'], $mysqli_config['user'], $mysqli_config['password'], $mysqli_config['dbname']);
$db::read_first_line('SELECT * FROM `admins`');
```

Comment: Чтобы итерироваться по результату query должно возвращать mysqli_result, а не true.

Answer (score 0):

Как я и думал, проблема была в функции query()

```
public static function query($query)
{
   return $result = mysqli_query(self::$mysqli_link, $query)
       or die("Ошибка запроса".mysqli_error(self::$mysqli_link));
}
```

Не работало, но вот так

```
public static function query($query)
{
   $result = mysqli_query(self::$mysqli_link, $query)
       or die("Ошибка запроса".mysqli_error(self::$mysqli_link));
    return $result;
}
```

заработало. Фантастика!
Для справки - php7.1 ; MySQL - 5.7 Может кому поможет.